# . How do I parentNode.removeChild(); a div. With the name in an array? (plain Java Script)

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I know that the title sounds weird but I don´t know how to exactly describe my problem. I have an array with all the divs id I created before. Now I want to take the first div´s id and remove the div by parentNode.removeChild(); The console prints:
'The "removeChild" property of an undefined or null reference can not be retrieved.'

I hope you can help me with that :)

```js
var animation_time = 1500;
var div_id_selection = [];//it contains 'div0', div1, div2 ... divn
var array_counter = -1;

// Before that is a function that creates a div by document.createElement("div); with the id div0, div1, div2 ...than it writes the id into the array:
  div_id_selection.push('div' + id);

var delete_divs = function(){

                  setTimeout(function(){
                  array_counter += 1;
                  var div_to_delete = div_id_selection[array_counter];
                  //var div_to_delete_str = div_to_delete.toString(); I already tried it with the string-didn´t work
                  console.log(div_to_delete);
                  console.log(array_counter);
                  div_to_delete.parentNode.removeChild(div_to_delete); // here is the problem
                  }, animation_time);
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`div_to_delete` is a string ( `id` that is stored in the array ).

`parentNode` method is only available on a `DOM` object.

You will have to first select the element using the `id`.

```
// get the correct DOM object using the array
var elem = document.getElementById(div_to_delete);
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
```